# Can 2 transactions of the same block update the same state key?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I believe the answer is no but I'd like confirmation.

With Fabric, endorsers simulate the transaction upon latest state and prepare the proposal adding the read and write set of keys.
At the commit phase, the peer will receive a block from the ordering service and the write set update is only applied if the read set has not been updated (versioning check). 
So for the same block, the same key cannot be updated by 2 different transactions of the same block.

If it is the case, aggregating value and maintaining balance on-chain might be problematic for frequent transactions use-case. Such operation should be left for off-chain application layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*So for the same block, the same key can not be updated by 2 different transactions of the same block.*

The above is correct.  Hyperledger Fabric uses an MVCC-like model in order to prevent collisions (or "double spend").  You'll want to wait for the previous state change transaction to commit before attempting to update the state again.

Comment: Does the ordering service take care that 2 transactions belonging to same block does not update the same key (by separating the 2 transactions in separate blocks)? Or does it throw an MVCC_READ_CONFLICT error?

Comment: The ordering service does not actually parse/process the transactions.  It just orderers and batches them (i.e. it does not look at the contents of the transaction).  Once a peer receives a block of transactions from the ordering service it actually does the validation (which includes the MVCC checks)

Comment: Thanks Gari. Then I assume in this case, I will get an MVCC_READ_CONFLICT error from the peer event. Right?

Comment: That's correct.  You should see the error code in the event

Comment: If anyone is concerned about the implication of this restriction in term of throughput, if the updated value of the key is a decimal, then there is workaround presented here [link]https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/high-throughput consisting of storing the only delta.